# Graphic representations of complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

Hello can someone help I've been doing some exercises about complex numbers. But I am not really good at reading their graphic representations. Can you guys tell me  if I did the exercise right, please?

The exercise: Let us consider the complex numbers z and w drawn in the Argand plane. What is the complex number u represented?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

1. I choose **-2z**
2. I choose  **the conjugate of z**
3. I choose **z + w**
4. I choose **1/w**
5. I choose **zw**

Comment: Can you rewrite your question to be a bit more clear? Are you being presented choices? What is $z$, what is $w$?

Comment: @scoopfaze I am sorry I hit the button submit with out adding the pictures

Comment: No worries, just trying to prevent downvotes

Comment: First three look alright. I’m skeptical of the last two

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: My apologies; I mixed up $w$ and $u$ in the last two. The colors threw me off

Comment: Don't worry. :)

Answer (score 1):

They are all correct. Pro-tip, when you multiply two complex numbers, you're adding their "angles" (with respect to the positive x-axis), so it makes sense that $zw$ is "between" $z$ and $w$.

Comment: Thamk you for the tip and help.